# Ruby on Rails database.yml information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I'm a designer and brand new to programming.

I have just opened my localhost and can see "Welcome aboard". It has 3 steps to complete - all of which simple to most, are complexing to me.

1. config/database.yml ok it wants to know my username and password. Where do I get these and where do I post them to to get them to work? I opened my database.yml and it is 
   SQLite version 3.x
   gem install sqlite3-ruby

I hear people talking about git and all this but confused on how to do these 3 steps -
   1.
      Create your databases and edit config/database.yml

```
  Rails needs to know your login and password.
```

2.
      Use script/generate to create your models and controllers

```
  To see all available options, run it without parameters.
```

3.
      Set up a default route and remove or rename this file

```
  Routes are set up in config/routes.rb.
```

Is this just too over my head? I wouldn't mind hiring someone to teach get it all going for me because I really want to learn to code Ruby on Rails.

Thanks!

Note - All resolved by deleting and reinstalling. Now I understand what is actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an SQLite database, you don't need to configure any username or password to get going with the database -- the default configuration should work out of the box and creates a new database file automatically for you.

For your other questions, the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide over at [guides.rubyonrails.org](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) is an excellent introduction that walks you through all the steps in creating a new Rails application.  Start by going through this tutorial step by step -- if you get stuck somewhere along the way you can always come back here and post follow-up questions.

Comment: Cool. I see it says this - $ gem install sqlite3-ruby for db. Is that what I type into the console? Even these beginner tuts are written techie because they are already programmers and not sure about how a non programmer would interpret it. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Yes.  Just leave out the $ at the beginning -- what you're actually typing in the console is `gem install sqlite3-ruby`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any idea what a database is you should just leave `database.yml` alone and use  the provided defaults (use sqlite, does not require a password/login). For getting started with Rails, this should be enough. Just delete the `public/index.html` file.

I would really recommend you to [buy a book (Rails 3)](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) (3rd edition is for Rails 2.3) which guides you through the creation of a Rails app - with a lot of examples. The [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are an alternative, but also might be a little difficult to read with close-to-none preknowledge of programming.

Comment: I know what a db is. I have setup up a WordPress install before. I just bought this book Simply Rails 2, but it's too outdated it seems and I got stuck on the install before this. I will check out your book recommendation though. Yea, the book I got was for designers to learn RoR so I figured it was the best. Once I get into the coding I should pick it up if I can ever launch from an editor to a browser. lol

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/) helpful. It's available for purchase as a PDF or you can view the [online version](http://railstutorial.org/book) for free. It covers all the major steps of developing a Rails application, including using Git.

Comment: @Ken You didn't mention anything about Windows.

Comment: I realized that after I posted. :)